# Im trying to push values from an array with objects to another array with objects

Tags: angular, typescript

I have multiple slides and based on those slides i want to make links that go to the slides but i want the generation of the navigation links to go automatic and its not working

im kinda new at angular and typescript so im at a loss

this is the generation of the links:

```
export class LinksComponent implements OnInit {
  links:Link[];

  constructor(private sS:SlidesService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    let slides = this.sS.getSlides();
    for (let s of slides) {
      let obj = {} as Link;
      obj.name = s.name;
      obj.href = "#" + s.name;
      obj.selected = false;
      this.links.push(obj);
    }
  }

}
```

sS is a service and the getSlides calls this function:

```
getSlides() {
    return [
      {
        name: "home",
        index: 1,
        selected:true,
        background:"url(bg_home.jpg)"
      },
      {
        name: "me",
        index: 2,
        selected:true,
        background:"url(bg_me.jpg)"
      },
      {
        name: "projects",
        index: 3,
        selected:true,
        background:"url(bg_projects.jpg)"
      }
    ]
  }
```

i get this error
ERROR typeError: cannot read property 'push' of undefined
even though i defined links(the array im trying to push objects in)
now i have looked for some answers but im at a loss. any help would be much appreciated

I want it to work so my links get dynamically made from the amount of slides with the corresponding name and stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have defined, but not initialized the array.

The example, boiled down to the issue:

**test.ts**

```
let links: Link[];
```

Is compiled to a **test.js**:

```
var links;
```

As you can see, `links` is not defined and therefore is `undefined`.

To solve the issue, initialize `links` as an empty array:

**test2.ts**:

```
let links: Link[] = [];
```

compiles to:

```
var links = [];
```

[Here's a TypeScript Playground showing the behavior.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/MYGwhgzhAEAyCWA7A1tA3gXwFAgKYBdoQlkIAuOEgbQF0BuLLAeiegE95cQATGMRaLgBOQgPZCyOEhAB0ABwCuEABYAKRLgDulFKoCUehs1abxpHASLSATBQQpa0ALzRaDYigjX5StRu32yPqGQA)

Answer (score 1):

This is because you have not defined your Links array, use something like below :

```
links:Link[] = [];
```

You are trying to push a new element to an undefined array thus getting the error as "cannot read property 'push' of undefined".

Comment: Appreciate all the fast answers

Answer (score 1):

`Links` is undefined, in fact in your code there is:

```js
 links:Link[];
```

To be able to `push` something in your array you must declare it as:

```js
 links:Link[] = [];
```

Or if you don't want to declare it , you have to assign value to it

Comment: Thanks i mean it makes sense now

Answer (score 1):

As the others have point out, you need to initialize links, before you can push into it.

Alternatively, you could do something like the example below, and you wouldn't need to initialize an empty array.

```
export class LinksComponent implements OnInit {
  links:Link[];

  constructor(private sS:SlidesService) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    // you want to use "const", when you are not resetting the value. 
    // Also a good idea to slap a type on what you get from your api requests.

    const slides: Slide[] = this.sS.getSlides();
    this.links = slides.map((s: Slide) => {
       return {
                 name: s.name,
                 href: '#' +s.name,
                 selected: false,
              }
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Juat add in the constructor:

```
export class LinksComponent implements OnInit {
  links:Link[];

  constructor(private sS:SlidesService) {
       this.links=[];
 }

  ngOnInit() {
    let slides = this.sS.getSlides();
    for (let s of slides) {
      let obj = {} as Link;
      obj.name = s.name;
      obj.href = "#" + s.name;
      obj.selected = false;
      this.links.push(obj);
    }
  }

}
```

and every thing will work fine.

(Of course, this comment is correct for the initialization of any object to which you want to insert values. You need to reformat it in its default value.)